# Excel chart - Not getting Legends

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I am creating an excel chart using C# (interop). I am using get_Range function to get it from the data sheet in excel. I am getting the graph properly. But I am not getting the ***Legend names*** next to graph, it is coming as series0, series1. I am using folowing code.

```
    Range chartRange;
    Object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)sheet0.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
    ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 70, 250, 250);
    Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
    Chart chartPage1 = myChart.Chart;
    chartRange = sheet0.get_Range("$G$45:$G$54,$AT$45:$AT$54", misValue);
    chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
    chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
    chartPage.Location(XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet, "Chart");
```

What shoud I change in get_Range method to get the Legend names in chart?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the legend should be an element of the chart, no independet object. 
To get the legend names, just iterate over the Chart.dataseries object and get their names.
Beware: it starts at 1 and ends at dataseries.count, starting at 0 does not raise an error, but produces crazy results. Also, you have to cast the objects several times.
I cannot provide sample code, because i have no Visual Studio at my workplace.

Comment: Legend is coming as series0, series1. I want to rename them. How?

Comment: Rename the series in the chart - that should update the legend as well.
The legend object should have something like a name property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to iterate over series collection and set the names one by one. Something like this:

```
foreach (Series series in myChart.SeriesCollection()){
   series.Name = "MyName";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the data is arranged so that if the series are in columns, the first column of the data has the X values for all series, the rest of the columns are the Y values, and the first row of the data has the series names, which are shown in the legend. To make sure Excel is able to parse the data this way, make sure the top left cell is blank. Use the entire range, including X values in the first column and the series names in the first row, as the chart range in SetSourceData.