# I am having problems in creating excel chart using C#

Tags: c#, excel, graph

I am having two problems while creating Excel charts through code.

Problem no.1 is that I want to know how should I set the chart property to create on lets say Cells[10,2] because its drawing the graph over the cells which contains the data. Below is the code I used to create the excel chart.

```
Excel.Range chartRange;
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)sheet2.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80,500,200);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "CHART from Code";
chartRange = sheet2.get_Range("B2", "M"+xlRow);

chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked;`
```

Now problem no.2 is that it creates a graph as I wanted but it uses the legends also in the bars and in the legends section of the graph it show series1,series2 and so on. I hope you guys understands the problems I am facing.
Looking forward for the responses.

Comment: 1. In your call `xlCharts.Add(10, 80,500,200);`, the `10` and `80` should be the position in points relative to the top left of A1 cell. Does the position of the chart change when you play change them?

Comment: 2. I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if your problem is setting the correct names for the data series, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14945206/4760587

Comment: @MarekFekete Thanks mate .... problem solved I changed the `xlCharts.Add(10, 80,500,200);` to `xlCharts.Add(750, 20,500,200);`. And for problem no 2 I was selecting an entire blank row which I corrected and the problems are solved.

Comment: Great. I've added the chart position as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the call `xlCharts.Add(10, 80,500,200)`, `10,80` are the coordinates of the desired position in points, relative to A1 cell.